# Nested list comprehension with two lists

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension

I understand how the simple list comprehension works eg.:

```
[x*2 for x in range(5)] # returns [0,2,4,6,8]
```

and also I understand how the nested list comprehesion works:

```
w_list = ["i_have_a_doubt", "with_the","nested_lists_comprehensions"]

# returns the list of strings without underscore and capitalized
print [replaced.title() for replaced in [el.replace("_"," ")for el in w_list]]
```

so, when I tried do this

```
l1 = [100,200,300]
l2 = [0,1,2]
[x + y for x in l2 for y in l1 ]
```

I expected this:

```
[100,201,302]
```

but I got this:

```
[100,200,300,101,201,301,102,202,302]
```

so I got a better way solve the problem, which gave me what I want

```
[x + y for x,y in zip(l1,l2)]
```

but I didn't understood the return of 9 elements on the first code

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The reason it has 9 numbers is because python treats

```
[x + y for x in l2 for y in l1 ]
```

similarly to

```
for x in l2:
    for y in l1:
       x + y
```

ie, it is a nested loop

Answer (score 35):

List comprehensions are equivalent to for-loops. Therefore, `[x + y for x in l2 for y in l1 ]` would become:

```
new_list = []
for x in l2:
    for y in l1:
        new_list.append(x + y)
```

Whereas `zip` returns tuples containing one element from each list. Therefore `[x + y for x,y in zip(l1,l2)]` is equivalent to:

```
new_list = []
assert len(l1) == len(l2)
for index in xrange(len(l1)):
    new_list.append(l1[index] + l2[index])
```

Answer (score 23):

The above answers will suffice for your question but I wanted to provide you with a list comprehension solution for reference (seeing as that was your initial code and what you're trying to understand).

Assuming the length of both lists are the same, you could do:

```
[l1[i] + l2[i] for i in range(0, len(l1))]
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can enumerate one of the lists, so you will only have to index one of them.

Comment: xrange is much better memory optimized

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein It's a bit late, but in python 3, range is equal to xrange.

Answer (score 3):

```
[x + y for x in l2 for y in l1 ]
```

is equivalent to :

```
lis = []
for x in l:
   for y in l1:
      lis.append(x+y)
```

So for every element of `l` you're iterating `l2` again and again, as `l` has 3 elements and `l1` has elements so total loops equal 9(`len(l)*len(l1)`).

Answer (score 2):

this sequence

`res = [x + y for x in l2 for y in l1 ]`

is equivalent to

```
res =[]
for x in l2:
    for y in l1:
        res.append(x+y)
```