# How to join strings from a Cartesian product of two lists

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation, cartesian-product

I have two lists of strings:

```
letters = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
numbers = ['123', '456']
```

I want to for loop through them to create a list of strings that is *not* parallel, so `zip()` doesn't work here.

Desired outcome:

```
result = ['abc123', 'def123', 'ghi123', 'abc456', 'def456', 'ghi456']
```

The order of the elements in the result is irrelevant.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your problem with two nested for loops?

Comment: @Wolf precisely what I was looking for! I just couldn't name it! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating Strings: "Multiplication" of two list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689672/concatenating-strings-multiplication-of-two-list-of-strings)

Comment: Also: [Cartesian product of two lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52192855/7851470)

Comment: Also: [concatenate strings in 2 different lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36885876/7851470)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try *list comprehension* with two nested for loop over `numbers` and then `letters` :

```
print([l+n for n in numbers for l in letters])
# ['abc123', 'def123', 'ghi123', 'abc456', 'def456', 'ghi456']
```

You can also use *nested for loop*:

```
out = []
for n in numbers:
    for l in letters:
        out.append(l+n)
print(out)
# ['abc123', 'def123', 'ghi123', 'abc456', 'def456', 'ghi456']
```

For more details on list comprehension, see either the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or this [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568056/nested-list-comprehension-with-two-lists).

Answer (score 4):

Take the product of `numbers` and `letters` (rather than `letters` and `numbers`), but then join the resulting tuples in *reverse* order.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [''.join([y, x]) for x, y in product(numbers, letters)]
['abc123', 'def123', 'ghi123', 'abc456', 'def456', 'ghi456']
```

For 2-tuples, `y + x` would be sufficient rather than using `''.join`.

The product of two lists is just the set of all possible tuples created by taking an element from the first list and an element from the second list, in that order.

```
>>> list(product(numbers, letters))
[('123', 'abc'), ('123', 'def'), ('123', 'ghi'), ('456', 'abc'), ('456', 'def'), ('456', 'ghi')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your lists of prefixes `letters` and suffixes `numbers` that have to be combined

```py
letters = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
numbers = ['123', '456']
```

### Basic

The first solution that comes to mind (especially if you are new to Python) is using nested loops

```py
result = []
for s in letters:
    for n in numbers:
        result.append(s+n)
```

and since - as you said - order is irrelevant, also the following will be a valid solution

```py
result = []
for n in numbers:
    for s in letters:
        result.append(s+n)
```

The most important downside of both is that you need to define the `result` variable before in a way that looks a bit weak.

### Advanced

If you switch to [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you can eliminate that extra line

```py
result = [s+n for n in numbers for s in letters]
```

### Expert

Mathematically spoken, you are creating the [*Cartesian product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of `numbers` and `letters`. Python provides a function for exact that purpose by [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) (which, by the way, also eliminates the double `for`s)

```py
from itertools import product
result = [''.join(p) for p in product(letters, numbers)]
```

this may look like overkill in your very example, but as soon as it comes to more components for building results, it may be a big difference, and all tools presented here but `itertools.product` will tend to explode then.

For illustration, I conclude with an example that loops over prefixes, infixes, and postfixes:

```py
print([''.join(p) for p in product('ab', '+-', '12')])
```

that gives this output:

```
['a+1', 'a+2', 'a-1', 'a-2', 'b+1', 'b+2', 'b-1', 'b-2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers! I simplified the case, so all of the above solutions work well, however in the real problem I'm working on I want to add more lines of code in between that would iterate through both lists. I completed it nesting those for loops:

```
for letter in letters:
   for number in numbers:
      print(letter+number)
      # many many lines of more code
```

Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The *many many lines of more code* should be probably [factored out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring#Techniques) into a function :)