# How to create lists from a cartesian product of two string lists

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, cartesian-product

I have two string lists that look like this:

```
print(objects_list)
print(verb_list)
```

they output:

```
['parking_meter', 'sink', 'teddy_bear']
 
 ['sail', 'fill', 'fly', 'greet', 'hit', 'hose', 'hunt', 'install',
 'kick', 'launch', 'move', 'pick', 'repair', 'sit_at', 'squeeze',
 'stab', 'straddle', 'talk_on']
```

I want product of these two lists in a format that looks like this:

```
[['parking_meter','sail'],['parking_meter','fill'],['parking_meter','fly']......]
```

I tried this code

```
list3 = [[str(l),str(n)] for l in objects_list for n in verb_list]
print(list3)
```

but it outputs:

```
[['[', '['], ['[', "'"], ['[', 's'], ['[', 'a'], ['[', 'i'], ['[',
 'l'], ['[', "'"], ['[', ','], ['[', ' '], ['[', "'"], ['[', 'f'],
 ['[', 'i'], ['[', 'l'], ['[', 'l'], ['[', "'"], ['[', ','], ['[', '
 '], ['[', "'"], ['[', 'f'], ['[', 'l'], ['[', 'y'], [.....
```

any solution?

Comment: check out `itertools`

Comment: why convert them to strings if you're just trying to get them as lists?

Comment: Possible duplicate (found by googling your title): [How to join strings from a Cartesian product of two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61678496/1324033)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, use the itertools library. There is a function called product that gets you a cartesian product.

```
import itertools

x = ['parking_meter', 'sink', 'teddy_bear']

y = ['sail', 'fill', 'fly', 'greet', 'hit', 'hose', 'hunt', 'install', 'kick', 'launch', 'move', 'pick', 'repair', 'sit_at', 'squeeze', 'stab', 'straddle', 'talk_on']
```

Then you can do this 2-liner, (because the product function returns a tuple but you require a list)

```
z = list(itertools.product(x,y))
z = [list(z) for z in z]
```

Or this 1-liner,

```
z = [list(tup) for tup in list(itertools.product(x, y))]
```

Then I,

```
print (z)
```

Which gives me

```
[['parking_meter', 'sail'],
 ['parking_meter', 'fill'],
 ['parking_meter', 'fly'],
 ['parking_meter', 'greet'],
 ['parking_meter', 'hit'],
 ['parking_meter', 'hose'],
 ['parking_meter', 'hunt'],
 ['parking_meter', 'install'],
 ['parking_meter', 'kick'],
 ['parking_meter', 'launch'],
 ['parking_meter', 'move'],
 ['parking_meter', 'pick'],
 ['parking_meter', 'repair'],
 ['parking_meter', 'sit_at'],
 ['parking_meter', 'squeeze'],
 ['parking_meter', 'stab'],
 ['parking_meter', 'straddle'],
 ['parking_meter', 'talk_on'],
 ['sink', 'sail'],
 ['sink', 'fill'],
 ['sink', 'fly'],......
```

Comment: I want lists not tuples

Comment: @RAFI i have edited my code

Comment: The use of itertools doesn't solve the initial issue, which was not the list comprehension but the fact that the initial lists were actually strings.

Answer (score 4):

Your code should work as is.  I suspect you have some other unnecessary str() function calls in your actual code:

```
objects_list = ['parking_meter', 'sink', 'teddy_bear']
verb_list = ['sail', 'fill', 'fly', 'greet', 'hit', 'hose',
             'hunt', 'install', 'kick', 'launch', 'move', 
             'pick', 'repair', 'sit_at', 'squeeze', 'stab', 
             'straddle', 'talk_on']

list3 = [[o,v] for o in objects_list for v in verb_list]

[['parking_meter', 'sail'], ['parking_meter', 'fill'], ['parking_meter', 'fly'], ['parking_meter', 'greet'], ['parking_meter', 'hit'], ['parking_meter', 'hose'], ['parking_meter', 'hunt'], ['parking_meter', 'install'], ['parking_meter', 'kick'], ['parking_meter', 'launch'], ['parking_meter', 'move'], ['parking_meter', 'pick'], ['parking_meter', 'repair'], ['parking_meter', 'sit_at'], ['parking_meter', 'squeeze'], ['parking_meter', 'stab'], ['parking_meter', 'straddle'], ['parking_meter', 'talk_on'], ['sink', 'sail'], ['sink', 'fill'], ['sink', 'fly'], ['sink', 'greet'], ['sink', 'hit'], ['sink', 'hose'], ['sink', 'hunt'], ['sink', 'install'], ['sink', 'kick'], ['sink', 'launch'], ['sink', 'move'], ['sink', 'pick'], ['sink', 'repair'], ['sink', 'sit_at'], ['sink', 'squeeze'], ['sink', 'stab'], ['sink', 'straddle'], ['sink', 'talk_on'], ['teddy_bear', 'sail'], ['teddy_bear', 'fill'], ['teddy_bear', 'fly'], ['teddy_bear', 'greet'], ['teddy_bear', 'hit'], ['teddy_bear', 'hose'], ['teddy_bear', 'hunt'], ['teddy_bear', 'install'], ['teddy_bear', 'kick'], ['teddy_bear', 'launch'], ['teddy_bear', 'move'], ['teddy_bear', 'pick'], ['teddy_bear', 'repair'], ['teddy_bear', 'sit_at'], ['teddy_bear', 'squeeze'], ['teddy_bear', 'stab'], ['teddy_bear', 'straddle'], ['teddy_bear', 'talk_on']]
```

Comment: but it still ouputs the same result.when I write `for o in objects_list: print(o)` it gives me every character separately in separate lines. `[
'
p
a
r
k
i
n
g
_
m
e
t
e
r
'
,
 
'
s
i
n
k
'
,
 
'`

Comment: From the output, it looks like there are spurious `str` even before the code reproduced in OP. `objects_list` itself is a string representation of the list, not the list itself. (See my answer.)

Comment: The your objects_list and verb_list variables are probably string representations of the list, not actual Python lists.

Comment: Thank you. Let me check this issue

Answer (score 2):

From the output you get, it seems your input lists are strings, not lists.

As if `objects_list` was the output of `print(objects_list)`, not the list itself.

Therefore, when iterating over `objects_list`, rather than interating over list items, you are iterating over the characters of its string reprensentation:

```
"["
"'"
"p"
"a"
...
```

Your code is otherwise correct, except you don't need to cast the elements to string in the list comprehension.

```
list3 = [[l, n] for l in objects_list for n in verb_list]
```

Comment: Yes i am facing this issue you got it. What could be possible solution for that

Comment: Well it happens earlier in the code so we can't help you unless you show us how you set those lists.

Answer (score 2):

Your code worked just fine and gave me the expected output. I am not sure is there any other problem. May be your list is not declared like me...if you had created this list from another source...you should check the format.

Note: I have run this code on Python 3.9.5

```
objects_list = ['parking_meter', 'sink', 'teddy_bear']
verb_list = ['sail', 'fill', 'fly', 'greet', 'hit', 'hose', 'hunt', 'install', 'kick', 'launch', 'move', 'pick', 'repair', 'sit_at', 'squeeze', 'stab', 'straddle', 'talk_on'] 

list3 = [[str(l),str(n)] for l in objects_list for n in verb_list] 
print(list3)

Output:
[['parking_meter', 'sail'], ['parking_meter', 'fill'], ['parking_meter', 'fly']['parking_meter', 'greet'], ['parking_meter', 'hit'], ['parking_meter', 'hose'], ['parking_meter', 'hunt'], ['parking_meter', 'install'], ['parking_meter', 'kick'], ['parking_meter', 'launch'], ['parking_meter', 'move'], ['parking_meter', 'pick'], ['parking_meter', 'repair'], ['parking_meter', 'sit_at'], ['parking_meter', 'squeeze'], ['parking_meter', 'stab'], ['parking_meter', 'straddle'], ['parking_meter', 'talk_on'], ['sink', 'sail'], ['sink', 'fill'], ['sink', 'fly'], ['sink', 'greet'], ['sink', 'hit'], ['sink', 'hose'], ['sink', 'hunt'], ['sink', 'install'], ['sink', 'kick'], ['sink', 'launch'], ['sink', 'move'], ['sink', 'pick'], ['sink', 'repair'], ['sink', 'sit_at'], ['sink', 'squeeze'], ['sink', 'stab'], ['sink', 'straddle'], ['sink', 'talk_on'], ['teddy_bear', 'sail'], ['teddy_bear', 'fill'], ['teddy_bear', 'fly'], ['teddy_bear', 'greet'], ['teddy_bear', 'hit'], ['teddy_bear', 'hose'], ['teddy_bear', 'hunt'], ['teddy_bear', 'install'], ['teddy_bear', 'kick'], ['teddy_bear', 'launch'], ['teddy_bear', 'move'], ['teddy_bear', 'pick'], ['teddy_bear', 'repair'], ['teddy_bear', 'sit_at'], ['teddy_bear', 'squeeze'], ['teddy_bear', 'stab'], ['teddy_bear', 'straddle'], ['teddy_bear', 'talk_on']]
```